# Creating a 10x10 table from TableElement, TableRowElement and TableCellElement

Tags: html, gwt

I was following the [Large scale application development and MVP - Part II](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html) tutorial, and in the last selection (Optimized UIs - Dumb Views) it says, a table shouldn't be created element per element, but rather in one flush using a HTML element and creating the table with TableElement, TableRowElement and TableCellElement.

So I created the code based on their example, but it just writes the different HTML elements under each other. I guess my code explains better what it should be doing.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    HTML html = new HTML();
    html.setHTML(createTable());
    RootPanel.get().add(html);
}

public String createTable() {
    //create table
    TableElement table = Document.get().createTableElement();
    //create tbody
    TableSectionElement tbody = Document.get().createTBodyElement();
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    //Create 10 dummy rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        //insert at -1, which is per definition the last posiion
        TableRowElement row = tbody.insertRow(-1);
        //create 10 dummy columns
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            //insert at -1, which is per definition the last posiion
            TableCellElement cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            //set a dummy text
            String s = (Integer.toString(i) + " : "
                    + Integer.toString(j));
            cell.setInnerHTML(s);
        }
    }

    return table.getInnerHTML();
}
```

Any Idea whats why it's not creating a 10x10 table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd encourage you to replace that code with SafeHtmlBuilder, which should be even faster (no DOM manipulation at all).

Next, to your problem, you should wrap the table within a dummy container (say, a DivElement) and use getInnerHTML() on that container.

Answer (score 0):

Well simple mistake... I was returning `table.getInnerHTML();` which return the part starting at `<tbody>` and ending with `</toboy>`. Changing it to `table.toString();` fixed it!

Comment: No, toString() on an Element is not guaranteed to return the "outerHTML" (as it's called in IE); see my answer.